# creating fixed width with 960?

Tags: css, 960.gs

i use 24 columns fluid version of 960. the html looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container_24">
        <div id="header" class="grid_24">
            Welcome to my page
        </div>

        <div id="leftbar" class="grid_4">
            leftbar
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="grid_12">
            content
        </div>
        <div id="rightbar" class="grid_4">
            rightbar
        </div>
        <div id="ads" class="grid_4">
            ads
        </div>

        <div id="footer" class="grid_24">
            Footer
        </div>        
    </div>
</body>
```

i wonder how i can make the leftbar, rightbar and ads divs fixed width so that they dont get thinner when i resize the webbrowser to a smaller size. i want just the header, content and footer div to be fluid.

is this possible?

Comment: noname, off topic, I have seen you have been struggling with SOLR in the past... I am right where you was, and I am having a **** because there isn't any good documentation or tutorials on how to implement it into a php site. Could you contact me, and maybe help me out a bit? I have installed it, and I can query it, but I have some problems still.

Comment: give me your msn so i can add you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to fix, add a `min-width:whateverpx (for example: min-width:300px;)` rule to each column and specify the minimum width you're willing to 'tolerate' so as to avoid thinning down.

If you could post a live sample of your code, it would help greatly